# How can I forward a message in Go msgraph-sdk-go and include Cc and/or Bcc recipients?

Tags: go, microsoft-graph-api

Using the Go msgraph-sdk-go library, I am trying to forward a message.  If I only have a "To" recipient, I can do it without issue but if I have "Cc" and/or "Bcc" recipients, I cannot get them added to the message.

The normal requestBody (`users.NewItemMailFoldersItemMessagesItemForwardPostRequestBody()`) used with the `Forward().Post()` function only has a `SetToRecipients()` function but does not have `SetCcRecipients()` or `SetBccRecipients()` functions.

I went through various attempts at working around this but the closest I have come still does not work.  Instead of calling `Forward().Post()`, I call `CreateForward().Post()` instead, which creates a draft of the message, returning the message object (`models.Messageable`).

On that message object I am then able to call the `SetToRecipients()`, `SetCcRecipients()`, and/or `SetBccRecipients()` functions.  I then call `Patch()` on the message to save the changes to the server, then I call `Send()` but I keep getting an error indicating there are no recipients defined.

The code I am working with is (simplified) as follows:

```
func forwardMessage(id string, toRecipients []models.Recipientable, ccRecipients []models.Recipientable, bccRecipients []models.Recipientable) (success bool) {
    var err error
    var message models.Messageable
    var requestBody = users.NewItemMailFoldersItemMessagesItemForwardPostRequestBody()

    message, err = pClient.Users().ByUserId(cpMailbox).Messages().ByMessageId(id).CreateForward().Post(context.Background(), requestBody, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(getOdataErrorV1(err).Error())
        return false
    }

    message.SetToRecipients(toRecipients)
    if len(ccRecipients) > 0 {
        message.SetCcRecipients(ccRecipients)
    }
    if len(bccRecipients) > 0 {
        message.SetBccRecipients(bccRecipients)
    }

    message, err = pClient.Users().ByUserId(cpMailbox).Messages().ByMessageId(*message.GetId()).Patch(context.Background(), message, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(getOdataErrorV1(err).Error())
        return false
    }

    err = pClient.Users().ByUserId(cpMailbox).Messages().ByMessageId(*message.GetId()).Send().Post(context.Background(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(getOdataErrorV1(err).Error())
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Any help figuring this out would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going back and forth and trying numerous different scenarios, I finally found the solution!  I had to:

- Apply the To recipients to the requestBody BEFORE I called createForward.
- After I got the new (draft) message back from that call, I saved the new ID.
- Initialize a NEW message object and apply the Cc/Bcc recipients to that.
- Call Patch on the newID message, passing the re-initialized message object.
- Send the draft message.

The updated code is as follows:

```
func forwardMessage(id string, toRecipients []models.Recipientable, ccRecipients []models.Recipientable, bccRecipients []models.Recipientable) (success bool) {
    var err error
    var message models.Messageable
    var newID string
    var requestBody = users.NewItemMailFoldersItemMessagesItemForwardPostRequestBody()

    requestBody.SetToRecipients(toRecipients)

    message, err = pClient.Users().ByUserId(cpMailbox).Messages().ByMessageId(id).CreateForward().Post(context.Background(), requestBody, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(getOdataErrorV1(err).Error())
        return false
    }

    newID = *message.GetId()
        
    message = models.NewMessage()
    message.SetToRecipients(toRecipients)
    if len(ccRecipients) > 0 {
        message.SetCcRecipients(ccRecipients)
    }
    if len(bccRecipients) > 0 {
        message.SetBccRecipients(bccRecipients)
    }

    _, err = pClient.Users().ByUserId(cpMailbox).Messages().ByMessageId(newID).Patch(context.Background(), message, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(getOdataErrorV1(err).Error())
        return false
    }

    err = pClient.Users().ByUserId(cpMailbox).Messages().ByMessageId(newID).Send().Post(context.Background(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(getOdataErrorV1(err).Error())
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```